# Connection refused by google sheets API, because daily quota reached

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota group 'ReadGroup' and limit 'Read requests per user per 100 seconds' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:changedthis'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Google developer console API key', 'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/project/changedthis/apiui/credential'}]}]}

My code sends data every 60 seconds and this only filling in 3 cells. Now I get the error at the start of my program. Do I wait for a few days or is this a permanent block?

Comment: per user per 100 seconds quota normally goes away after about five minutes but you should try and slow your application down a little so you dont hit it to often.

Comment: I waited for a few hours before trying again and I still got the error, that's why I asked. Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

### This is related to the usage limit

As per the [Sheets Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) says `There is no daily usage limit` but limited `requests per 100 seconds`. If you are owner of a billing account you can increase this quota. Otherwise `500 requests per 100 seconds per project` and `100 requests per 100 seconds per user` are the limit.

As a workaround make use of different service accounts in order to reach 500 requests / 100 seconds.

### Edit

Looking at your code these are the changes that are currently working (Take a look into the scopes, some of them are not necessary in this case, although I didn't modify them):

```
import gspread
import time
import datetime
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'creds.json'
 
#creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

creds = credentials.with_subject('user@yourdomain.com')
 
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
 
sheet = client.open_by_key("ID").sheet1  # Open the spreadsheet
 
i = 1
while True:
  cell = sheet.cell(i, 1).value
  i += 1
  if len(cell) == 0:  # of een manier om te kijken of de cell leeg is
      print("Empty row has been found at row", (i-1))
      break
    # ofzo, als er geen begrenzing is en geen lege cell dan blijft deze lus maar doorgaan     totdat sheet.cell(i, 1).value fout gaat denk ik
  if i > 1000:
      print("Did not find any empty rows")
      break
    
while True:
  x = str(datetime.datetime.now())
  sheet.update_cell(i, 1, x)  # Update one cell
  time.sleep(60)
```

In order to make this work, you should activate the [domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

### References

[Sheets API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits)

[Resolve a 429 error: Too many requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_429_error_too_many_requests)

Comment: I tried to connect again today and still getting blocked. I am only trying to send data every 60 seconds

Comment: In that case, can you please share a sanitized (no private information) code where you make those requests?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R1qJN5hxONHqUPh6JAJxM2F3wL0_pw-HurGKh82Lxx4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I reproduced your code and it's working, despite the third party library. I strongly recommend you to use the [Google Official OAuth2 library](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) and impersonate the specific user. Use the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) as a code base (you should modify the credentials part). Let me know if it works for you to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for Google Spreadsheet while writing to it and I logged the output data from my code to `local csv` file and then imported it into google sheets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).